# System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, task, httpclient

I am calling a simple Web Api service using HTTPClient. The service accepts a parameter, like URL and saves it in a SQL table, converts that url to guid and returns it back to the caller. The code below is used inside a SharePoint Web part which is called via a button click event handler.

```
public void DisplayUrl(string host,string paramUrl)
        {
            string longUrl = string.Format("https://{0}-UrlApi/AddUrl?longUrl={1}", host,paramUrl);
            var result = GetUrl(longUrl).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            tboxResults.Text = result.ShortUrl;
        }

protected static async Task<ShortUrlResponse> GetUrl(string baseUrl)
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {

        var response = client.GetAsync(baseUrl).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response1 = response;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ShortUrlResponse>(resp);
            return result;

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The web part is deployed to testing environment and when I open the page in the browser from a machine outside test server I get this error. At one point I was getting it inside the test server as well, but after I clicked the button a second time it worked correctly, but not in the dev machine for example.

This is the error that I am getting.

> Error message: One or more errors occurred.
>   InnerException: 
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The logon attempt failed at
>   System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob,
>   Boolean throwOnError, SecurityStatus& statusCode) at
>   System.Net.NTAuthentication.GetOutgoingBlob(String incomingBlob) at
>   System.Net.NegotiateClient.DoAuthenticate(String challenge, WebRequest
>   webRequest, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate) at
>   System.Net.NegotiateClient.Authenticate(String challenge, WebRequest
>   webRequest, ICredentials credentials) at
>   System.Net.AuthenticationManagerDefault.Authenticate(String challenge,
>   WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials) at
>   System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest
>   httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo) at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth() at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean&
>   disableUpload) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>
> TUrlControl:
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>   at AIntranet.WebParts.TUrl.TUrlUserControl.d__3.MoveNext()
>
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>        at AIntranet.WebParts.TUrl.TUrlUserControl.DisplayUrl(String host, String paramUrl)
>        at AIntranet.WebParts.TUrl.TUrlUserControl.b__1_0()
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback
>   secureCode, Object param)
>        at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated
>   secureCode)
>        at AIntranet.WebParts.TUrl.TUrlUserControl.btnTUrl_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Please add the error message itself as well, you included only the stacktrace

Comment: I have inserted the innerexception. I see that there is an (401) Unauthorized exception. I did not have this before. How can I run it will elevated privileges?

Comment: @BurreIfort a few things jump out at me, mixing async-await with `.Result` blocking calls can cause deadlocks. Continuously creating and disposing `HttpClient` can cause socket exhaustion.

Comment: @Nkosi, thank you for your reply and suggestions. Can you tell me how can I improve my code? Thank you once again.